# Center Java Alert on a JavaFX Node [For example a StackPane or a Button]

Tags: java, javafx, alert

Looking through the web i didn't found any solution . The below image explains what i want to achieve:

[image]

---

One possible solution was created for Computer with one Screen , for multiple Screens it needs modification. Although it works[for one Screen ] , i am not sure if this is the correct way to do it....

**Question:**
Is that the correct direction?It is possible that JavaFX has not build in such a functionality for `Nodes` and it has it only for `Stage`?

Code:

```
  /**
     * Makes a question to the user.
     *
     * @param text
     *            the text
     * @param node
     *            The node owner of the Alert
     * @return true, if successful
     */
    public static boolean doQuestion(String text, Node node) {
    questionAnswer = false;

    // Show Alert
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    alert.setHeaderText("");
    alert.setContentText(text);

    // Make sure that JavaFX doesn't cut the text with ...
    alert.getDialogPane().getChildren().stream().filter(item -> node instanceof Label)
        .forEach(item -> ((Label) node).setMinHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE));

    // I noticed that height property is notified after width property
    // that's why i choose to add the listener here
    alert.heightProperty().addListener(l -> {

        // Width and Height of the Alert
        int alertWidth = (int) alert.getWidth();
        int alertHeight = (int) alert.getHeight();

        // Here it prints 0!!
        System.out.println("Alert Width: " + alertWidth + " , Alert Height: " + alertHeight);

        // Find the bounds of the node
        Bounds bounds = node.localToScreen(node.getBoundsInLocal());
        int x = (int) (bounds.getMinX() + bounds.getWidth() / 2 - alertWidth / 2);
        int y = (int) (bounds.getMinY() + bounds.getHeight() / 2 - alertHeight / 2);

        // Check if Alert goes out of the Screen on X Axis
        if (x + alertWidth > InfoTool.getVisualScreenWidth())
        x = (int) (getVisualScreenWidth() - alertWidth);
        else if (x < 0)
        x = 0;

        // Check if Alert goes out of the Screen on Y AXIS
        if (y + alertHeight > InfoTool.getVisualScreenHeight())
        y = (int) (getVisualScreenHeight() - alertHeight);
        else if (y < 0)
        y = 0;

        // Set the X and Y of the Alert
        alert.setX(x);
        alert.setY(y);
    });
    return questionAnswer;
}
```

And the two methods missing from above:

```
/**
     * Gets the visual screen width.
     *
     * @return The screen <b>Width</b> based on the <b>visual bounds</b> of the
     *         Screen.These bounds account for objects in the native windowing
     *         system such as task bars and menu bars. These bounds are
     *         contained by Screen.bounds.
     */
    public static double getVisualScreenWidth() {
    return Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the visual screen height.
     *
     * @return The screen <b>Height</b> based on the <b>visual bounds</b> of the
     *         Screen.These bounds account for objects in the native windowing
     *         system such as task bars and menu bars. These bounds are
     *         contained by Screen.bounds.
     */
    public static double getVisualScreenHeight() {
    return Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this implementation of [JavaFX CenteredAlert](https://github.com/cdr89/javafx-centered-alert)

This implementation center the alert in the current screen, if you need to implement different centering logic you can do it editing the method centerAlertInStage()

Comment: Try to make it also work with a node in general and not only a Stage. +1 for your try.

Comment: Thank you @GOXR3PLUS, now it works given a Node. Fixed also the blinking on showing the dialog.

Comment: I will try it :)